# How to wire up a generic repository parameter

Tags: .net, autofac

I'm getting the following error:

None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'HotelsLive.Application.CompanyService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:

Cannot resolve parameter 'HotelsLive.Interfaces.Repositories.IRepositoryAsync`1[HotelsLive.Domain.Models.Company] repository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(HotelsLive.Interfaces.Repositories.IRepositoryAsync`1[HotelsLive.Domain.Models.Company])'.

The service constructor is:

```
    public CompanyService(IRepositoryAsync<Company> repository) : base(repository) {
        _companyRepository = repository;
    }
```

The Autofac registrations are:

```
        builder.RegisterType<CompanyService>()
                            .As<ICompanyService>()
                            .InstancePerRequest();
```

and

```
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
                .As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>))
                .InstancePerRequest();
```

I'm assuming I need to specify the parameter, but am not sure how to go about this. I've looked into the WithParameter method on the comapnyservice registration, but haven't been able to get anything to compile.

Comment: Your configuration is correct, and it should work. Check whether you accidentally defined multiple `IRepositoryAsync<T>` interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I did get it working eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually got there. Final consfiguration was:

```
        builder.RegisterType<CompanyService>()
                            .As<ICompanyService>()
                            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "repository", (p, c) => c.Resolve<IRepositoryAsync<Company>>()))
                            .InstancePerRequest();
```